# Can I check conditions for each id number and then return results in a new column, in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ID  Grade   Result
1   A       Good
1   B       Good
1   C       Good
1   D       Good
2   A       Good
2   B       Good
3   B       Bad
3   C       Bad
3   D       Bad
.
.
.
```

Can I check for conditions for each id number. If an id number has A and B then good, if an id number doesn't have an A and has a D then bad. I need some type of procedure or loop to check the condition for all id numbers and return a value in a new column. I really just need to know if this can be done in T-SQL? I have a table with hundreds of id numbers.

Comment: Sure, you are duly authorized. You can approach it using [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or `distinct`, `group by` and `having`. Try writing some code and posting it with a specific question. A loop is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
drop table #tmp
select 1 as ID,  'A' as Grade   into #tmp
union select 1,   'B' 
union select 1,   'C' 
union select 1,   'D' 
union select 2,   'A' 
union select 2,   'B' 
union select 3,   'B' 
union select 3,   'C' 
union select 3,   'D' 

select * from #tmp


select ID, Grade,
case when ID in (select ID from #tmp where Grade in ('A','B') group by ID having count(*)>=2) then 'Good' 
     when ID in (select ID from #tmp where Grade not in ('A')) and ID in (select ID from #tmp where Grade in ('D')) then 'BAD' end as Result
from #tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `SUM()` window function:

```
select t.ID, t.Grade,
  case
    when t.hasA > 0 and t.hasB > 0 then 'Good'
    when t.hasA = 0 and t.hasD > 0 then 'Bad'
    -- else ?
  end Result
from (
  select *,
    sum(case when Grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID) hasA,
    sum(case when Grade = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID) hasB,
    sum(case when Grade = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID) hasD
  from tablename
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=460a2ec30c35bfb0e4bfe0e60ad94848).

Results:

```
> ID | Grade | Result
> -: | :---- | :-----
>  1 | A     | Good  
>  1 | B     | Good  
>  1 | C     | Good  
>  1 | D     | Good  
>  2 | A     | Good  
>  2 | B     | Good  
>  3 | B     | Bad   
>  3 | C     | Bad   
>  3 | D     | Bad
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked best for me. The table above is arbitrary. The method I need to do is similar but different. It requires more cases and manipulation. I was able to incorporate this into what I needed. My only concern is the amount of case statements I am using. Also seeing if there is a way to read in order. For example if A comes after B then also 'bad'. Stuff like that.

Comment: You can't avoid the case statements. There must be as many as your conditions (at least). As for the order problem you must have another column that defines the order. What you see when doing a simple: `select * from tablename` is not an ordered resultset. Tables are unordered data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could  filter the proper set using  group by and having clause
antd merge he result uisng  union

the first select  check for both A and B grade  the second for D

```
select  id, grade, 'Good' Result 
from  my_table m1
INNER JOIN  (
  select id  
  from  my_table  
  where grade in ('A', 'B')
  group by id  
  having count(distict grade )  =  2
) t1 on t1.id = m1.id 
UNION 
select  id, grade, 'Bad'  
from  my_table m2
INNER JOIN  (
   select id  
   from  my_table  
   where grade  IN  ( 'A', 'D')
   group by id  
   having count(distict grade )  =  1
   INNER  JOIN  my_table m2 ON t2.id = m2.id and m2.grade ='D'
) t2 ON t2.id = m2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using string_agg function.

Please note only SQL Server 2017 or above version supports string_agg function.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT, GRADE VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
(1,   'B'),
(1,   'A'),
(1,   'C'),
(1,   'D'),
(2,   'A'),
(2,   'B'),
(3,   'B'),
(3,   'C'),
(3,   'D')

;WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(GRADE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GRADE) AS GRADE_STRING
FROM TEST
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT TEST.ID, TEST.GRADE,
CASE WHEN GRADE_STRING LIKE '%A%B%' THEN 'GOOD'
     WHEN GRADE_STRING LIKE '%D%' AND GRADE_STRING NOT LIKE '%A%' THEN 'BAD'
     END AS RESULTS
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN TEST
ON CTE.ID = TEST.ID
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f02e71ead8fcf8a2abb9cc2176c0b948)

Comment: How does `String_Agg` without an `order by` clause ensure that `'A'` will come before `'B'` in the string? The `like` pattern won't match if it happens the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and `case`:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when grade not in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'good'
             when sum(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
                  sum(case when grade = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'bad'
             else 'middling'
        end) as overall
from t
group by id;
```

Note that I interpreted your first condition as "ids having only 'A's and 'B's."

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
 select a.ID,a.Result
 into #tmp2 from 
 (select ID, 'Good' Result from #yourtable where Grade='A') a
 inner join 
 (select ID, 'Good' Result from #yourtable where Grade='B' ) b
 on a.ID=b.ID

 select t.ID,t.Grade,ISNULL(t2.Result,'Bad') Result
 into #result
 from #yourtable t
 left join #tmp2 t2
 on t.ID=t2.ID

 select * from #result
```